# Run playbook file on particular days

Tags: loops, cron, ansible, job-scheduling

I am new to Ansible, I need to execute one playbook file for 7 days alone and 8th day I need to run another playbook file. How can I set that using Ansible? I have tried at module but it's not applicable to that. How can I set conditions as per my requirement?

I have created sample job using Ansible. In which I need to run my job every day once and up to 7 days alone, so that I specify 24 hrs once in hour filed and in day field as 01-07. Here is my code:

```
- - cron:
        name: "play mail"
        hour: "24"
        day: "01-07"
        job: "sh script.sh"
```

I am able to run this code without any error and job created I have seen using `crontab -l`. But it executes only once. Not every 24 hrs of 7 days. Whether it's correct as per my requirement?

Comment: Are you trying to run a playbook only on particular days, or are you trying to use Ansible to configure cron to run a command only on particular days?  And to be sure, you're referring to the 1st through 7th days of the month, correct?

Comment: Yes i need to run a task file for seven days alone,in which i added my playbook file like ansible-playbook myplayfile.yml in my script and running that in a job for the specified days,The next 8th day i need to execute another task file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your need.

If you have to start the playbook on the control machine for x days, I don't think you need Cron module. Just make a crontab entry with `crontab -e` on the control machine scheduled for 7 days, and a second one for the 8th.
crontab entries on control machine will run something like:

```
# Every day at midnight
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook1_7.yml

# Every 8 days
0 0 */8 * * /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook8.yml
```

You can refine the timing by testing on http://www.cronsandbox.com/

Ansible cron module is useful if your playbook has to manage crontab entries on the target hosts, so from the control machine you run a playbook to create, update, remove or check crontab entries on remote hosts. Of course you could run the playbook on localhost too.

In Ansible cron module "days" means "Day of the month". So 01-07 should schedule a job to run from the 1st to the 7th day of any months.

Comment: hey thanks Lenti...But you mention everyday at midnight?Here too i need to send mails for everyday but for 7 days alone,like a warning mail.So how can i mention it for sending mail upto 7 days alone???

Comment: e.g. 0 0 9-15 9 * schedules cron job from the 9th to the 15th of september (but every year, so if you need that just for 2016 you'll remove the cron entry before september 2017 or concatenate a test and the command like "0 0 9-15 9 * test $(date +\%Y) -eq 2016 &&  scriptSendingMail.sh "). In your previous example 1-7 would schedule from 1st to 7th. There are a lot of examples on internet about crontab. See https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html and check your scheduling online by http://www.cronsandbox.com